# what is the difference between ISE and Vivado?

Tags: ise, vivado

I am xilinx ISE and virtex 5 engineer.

I found Vivado something when I ran across the internet.
What is the difference between ISE and Vivado?

Should I have to move to Vivado from ISE?

Comment: This is a better question for your Xilinx salesperson or applications engineer than for us. At least since several years ago Xilinx was already recommending to switch to Vivado (for new projects).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vivado is Xilinx's next-generation replacement for ISE.  It was released in 2012, and since 2013 there have been no new versions of ISE.  You have to use Vivado if you're working with the 7-series FPGAs* or newer.  However, Vivado cannot target older FPGAs including the Virtex 5, so you're stuck with ISE for those.

* (with some limited exceptions - ISE can target some Zynq and Artix devices, but it's not recommended)

Comment: Additions: ISE 14.7 (last release version from Oct. 2013) can also handle Kintex-7 and Virtex-7 devices, but not the full list. Parts of Vivado were formerly known as PlanAhead (shipped with ISE). Its amazing to see such an old product lacking so much features from ISE and having even more bugs ...

Comment: @Paebbels this isnthe off the topic but wouldnyou let me know what is the difference between kintex and virtex5,7? Is there any special different for use?

Comment: @nashile, FPGAs are complex parts. There's no shortcut to reading the datasheets (at least chapter 1) to find out the differences between them.

Comment: From (slow, small, less features) to (fast, huge, many features): Artix, Kintex, Virtex. Zynq is with embedded ARM CPU.